# Using foreach parsing of stdClass Object data in php

Tags: php, soap, foreach

This is the results of a call to function using with a soap client function and no matter what I do, I can't seem to parse the results and get the list of SKUs out of the array.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetFilteredSkuListResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Status] => Success
        [MessageCode] => 0
        [ResultData] => stdClass Object
        (
            [string] => Array
            (
                [0] => XYZ2802
                [1] => XYZ2808
                [2] => XYZ2850
                [3] => XYZ2848
                [4] => XYZ2846
            )

        )

    )

)
```

I'm using this in PHP to parse the result but it's not echoing anything?

```
foreach ($result->GetFilteredSkuListResult->ResultData as $message) {
    echo $message->string;
}
```

Comment: It should be echoing `Array`, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the string part:

```
foreach ($result->GetFilteredSkuListResult->ResultData->string as $message) {
  echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ResultData is not the array, string is.

Try

```
foreach ($result->GetFilteredSkuListResult->ResultData->string as $message) {
    echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `$message` is the array ['string'].
So you can't echo the array, use `print_r($message)` to view the data.
to access data in index[0] use `echo $message[0];`